# How to invoke sudo command from Ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, macos, sudo

want to update /etc/hosts from Ruby, so i have below code in my ruby script

```
system("sudo echo 'some.valid.ip.address some.domain.name.com' >> /etc/hosts")
```

expecting it will prompt for password, however i got below permission denied error

```
-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

any thought what is the right way to make the call?

Comment: You are only running the `echo` under `sudo`, the redirection (`>> /etc/hosts`) is part of the shell, which runs as you.

Comment: The linked "duplicate" question is specifically about Rails, not Ruby in general. The answers focus on Rails specific solutions. I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Jörg is right, and actually that makes this question a different one that the marked "duplicate".
The solution is to run the whole "echo 'some.valid.ip.address some.domain.name.com' >> /etc/hosts" as sudo, for that you need to write it that way: `sudo bash -c 'echo \"some.valid.ip.address some.domain.name.com\" >> /etc/hosts'

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible, you can run the Ruby script as root and it will work.